# Why was a perfectly valid question closed?

Tags: support, status-completed

Sorry but I don't understand why was the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101371/asp-net-mvc-3-navigation-via-jquery-ui-tabs/11115792) closed by [@casperOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone). The question seems to explain perfectly what the user has tried and the problem he has encountered. You can't ask for a better description. He provided all the details allowing to reproduce the problem.

It's true that the [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/537edeb3-675a-4e21-b4c6-b92c9b297518/view-source) posted on Jun 19 at 12:53 was total crap and didn't make any sense and deserved closing. But the OP [edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c8007d52-bbbf-49c9-9640-15b1d0dedda2/view-source) on Jun 20 at 8:16 and the question seemed perfectly clear. He provided more than enough details.

I answered it on Jun 20 at 8:40 and the question was closed on Jun 20 at 13:10.

So I just wanted to ask what the community thinks about this and whether the question should be reopened or not. I've already expressed my opinion under the form of a reopen vote.

Comment: Looks like it's been reopened.

Comment: BTW, wouldn't a flag asking to reopen the question have been much easier?  Look at all this typing you made both of us do =)

Comment: The title of this makes me laugh.

Comment: `closed as too localized by casperOne♦` ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The flag was basically too old (the user made an edit after the flag) and I didn't see the revision history.  It's reopened.